# Pip Install Timeout Issue

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am trying to install pandas in my company computer.
I tried to do

```
pip install pandas
```

but operation retries and then timesout.

then I downloaded the package:

pandas-0.22.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

and install:

```
pip install pandas-0.22.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64
```

But I get the following error:

> ```
> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
> status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x0000000003F16320>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
> out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytz/
>       Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x0000000003F16C50>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
> out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytz/
>       Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x0000000003F16C18>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
> out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytz/
>       Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x0000000003F16780>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
> out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytz/
>       Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x0000000003F16898>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed
> out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytz/
>       Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz>=2011k (from pandas==0.22.0) (from versions: )
>     No matching distribution found for pytz>=2011k (from pandas==0.22.0)
> ```

I did the same with package: `pandas-0.22.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

I also tried to use proxies:

```
pip --proxy=IND\namit.kewat:xl123456@192.168.180.150:8880 install numpy
```

But I am unable to get pandas.

when I tried to access the site : https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files I can access it without any problem on explorer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Comment: Did you try upgrading your pip to the latest version available?

Comment: Related: [How to solve ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443) with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43298872/1364007)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`PIP` has a default timeout of `15 sec`, [reference guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/). `Pandas` is a relatively big file, at 10MB, and it's dependant `Numpy`, at 20MB could still be needed (if it is not installed already.). In addition, your network connection may be slow. Therefore, set `PIP` to take longer time by, for example, giving it `1000 sec`:

```
pip --timeout=1000 install pandas
```

as suggested by @Pouya Khalilzad.

Comment: Nowadays the parameter seems to be called `--timeout`, not `--default-timeout` .

Comment: @asmaier, noted. It makes it easier by being shorter.

Answer (score 73):

This works for me:

```
pip --default-timeout=1000 install pandas
```

Comment: Note: the option is now `--timeout`, **NOT** `--default-timeout`

Answer (score 17):

In my case, my network was configured to use IPV6 by default, so I changed it to work with IPV4 only.

You can do that in the Network connections section in the control panel:

`'Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections'`

[image]

Than disable the IPV6 option:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me like magic, for some days I couldn't install anything with `pip install`.

Comment: Thanks! For weird reason it worked. Any idea why this might be an issue?

Comment: It seems that we all are from Israel. There is a chance that you all are connected with HotBox to the internet? I believe that theirs IP6 have some knows issues...

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue on my server by following command because the timeout not helped me.

```
sudo ip link set eth0 mtu 1450
```

In my case problem was in network and ddos protection on my ubuntu 20 server. Hope it'll be helpfull for someone.

More about MTU here https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size

Answer (score 0):

try below command:

you can replace package as per your needs

ex:

pip install selenium -vv --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --trusted-host pypi.org  --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

Answer (score 0):

- Windows 10 with WSL2 Ubuntu
- pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

For me `sudo su` then `pip3 install LIBRARY` did a job. The problem is probably firewall setting that makes pip unallowed to make requests.

This is not a solution, i just found a problem that can be solved in several ways. Check your antivirus, environments like WSL firewalls and then try again.