# PIP Install pysftp: Connect Timeout

Tags: python, pip, sftp, pysftp

I am very new to python and want to start working with the pysftp module in Python. However when follwoing instructions found here

[here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/python-secure-ftp-module)https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/python-secure-ftp-module

I believe due to the timeout it cant reach something, but I have no idea how to understand this.

```
C:\Users\userno1>cd c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\Scripts

c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\Scripts>pip search pysftp
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connecti
on broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000048EE358>, 'Connection to pypi.p
ython.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connecti
on broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000048FC9E8>, 'Connection to pypi.p
ython.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connecti
on broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000048FCA58>, 'Connection to pypi.p
ython.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connecti
on broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000048FCBA8>, 'Connection to pypi.p
ython.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connecti
on broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connect
ion.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000048FCCF8>, 'Connection to pypi.p
ython.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /pypi
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 578, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 351, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 814, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 147, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.timeout))
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<pip._ven
dor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000
00000048FCE48>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\adapters.py", line 403, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 651, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 651, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 651, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 651, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 651, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 623, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 281, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionP
ool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi (Cau
sed by ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.Ver
ifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000048FCE48>, 'Connection to pypi.python.o
rg timed out. (connect timeout=15)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecomman
d.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\s
earch.py", line 43, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\s
earch.py", line 60, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1092
, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1432
, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\download.p
y", line 764, in request
    headers=headers, stream=True)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\sessions.py", line 518, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\download.p
y", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\ca
checontrol\adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "c:\Users\userno1\AppData\Local\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\re
quests\adapters.py", line 459, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.p
ython.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi (Caused by ConnectTi
meoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnec
tion object at 0x00000000048FCE48>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (c
onnect timeout=15)'))
```

Comment: See [Pip Install Timeout Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50305112/850848).

Comment: Apologies, I am very new to programming. Especially surrounding PIP and Python work.  I did not download using Anaconda, I used JetBrains Pycharm. Additionally I have tried using `pip --default-timeout=1000 install pysftp`, however I still get the same errors. And the question linked in the comments there, are run on a MAC, which will not work on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I have a list of what worked and didnt work:

**What worked?**

`conda install pysftp`

**What didnt work?**

`pip install pysftp`

`python -m pip install pysftp`

Answer (score 0):

I had problems installing pysftp with conda because no linux-armv7l package was available.

**I solved it by:**

```
apt-get install paramiko
pip install pysftp
```

The pip package seams to have some dependencies on paramiko.
Perhaps it works also for different architektures