# Changing read timed out limit in pip when installing multiple packages using anaconda

Tags: pip, conda

I an installing environment.yml file via

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

But I get

> raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
> pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed

My environment.yml has a structure like this

```
name: relightable-nr
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies: 
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.3.7=h0b5b093_0
  - pip:
    - absl-py==0.8.0
    - astor==0.8.0
    - astroid==2.3.3
    - wrapt==1.11.2
    - xarray==0.13.0
prefix: /root/anaconda3/envs/envn
```

I read [How to solve ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443) with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port) and [Pip Install Timeout Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305112/pip-install-timeout-issue)
I changed my conda default timeout to 300 but how to change pip timeout in my case here?

Answer (score 0):

Pip will pull configuration options from a `pip.conf`/`pip.inf` (Unix/Win) file located in either a global, user, or environment scope, and settings such as `timeout` can be configured there. See [the Pip User Guide section on Config Files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file).

While that answers the question proper, I would be remiss were I not to mention that all the packages listed in the YAML can come from Conda. A more appropriate solution would be to reconfigure the YAML to not hit PyPI in the first place, e.g.,

```
name: relightable-nr
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies: 
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.3.7=h0b5b093_0
  - absl-py=0.8.0
  - astor=0.8.0
  - astroid=2.3.3
  - wrapt=1.11.2
  - xarray=0.13.0
```

but perhaps you abridged the YAML and left out packages that only have PyPI builds. Still, I would recommend getting everything possible from Conda.

Comment: thanks, I made the separate requirements file for pip packages and installed it. It didn't give timeout then. :)

Comment: @AvaniGupta You should really consider installing all the packages through Conda.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
sudo pip install --default-timeout=100 <name_of_your_library>
```

Comment: The OP has said that they read [Pip Install Timeout Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50305112/1364007) which suggested what you just said.