# pip timing out on multiple computers on the same network

Tags: python, networking, pip

I'm using pip regularly

right now i'm getting errors when trying to run
`pip install numpy`

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/ ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy`

I get the same error when running the command from my pc and also where running it from my laptop.

I had some internet connectivity issues the other day, also the problem seemed to occur after I installed
`pip install -U databricks-connect==7.1.*` ran some commands(`databricks-connect configure` and `databricks-connect test`) and then uninstalled it.

Again, the problem occurs on both computers connected to the same network.

Thanks
roy

Comment: This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305112/pip-install-timeout-issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be a network provider related problem