# cannot pip install the package due to python version

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, python-wheel

I got an issue about install a package. All my python is in anaconda. and I have multiple env. I have a wheel package need to be installed and I can't use conda install due to the company channel setting. The only way I can do is to download it and then pip install.

This package requires python 3.10 and I create a new virtual env in anaconda for python 3.10. After activate the env, I pip install the package, it will have some error message said that "xxxx(package name) requires Python '>=3.10' but the running python 3.6.4". But when I print
`python --version`
it shows python 3.10.12.

I have no idea what's the reason and I have stuck here for 2 days, any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Try `python -m pip install`, your environment might be a bit mangled and is pointing to the wrong `pip` by default.

Comment: I echo what @ThomasSatterly recommends. In fact, I almost never run pip any other way.

Comment: @ThomasSatterly Thank you for the suggestion. I tried but it shows: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026552648190>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pydantic/  Not sure this is due to what reason.

Comment: That might be a certificate issue -- are you on a VPN, behind a firewall, or using a proxy? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305112/pip-install-timeout-issue) for possible solutions.

Comment: @JRiggles please read the post first. OP has multiple conda envs already and is inside a conda env. These have nothing to do with `venv`