Pip fails with ReadTimeoutError on internal Artfactory
TLDR: Pip/mamba/conda keep failing with a timeout issue on arbitrary packages. Pip is set up to pull from an internal artifactory.
The contents of pip.conf
[global]
index-url = https://user:password@artifactory.myURL.com/artifactory/api/pypi/primary-pypi/simple
trusted-host = artifactory.myURL.com
ssl_verify: /usr/local/share/ca_certificates/my_cert.crt

[search]
index = https://user:password@artifactory.myURL.com/artifactory/api/pypi/primary-pypi/simple
cache-dir = ''

I cannot get it to fail consistently on a certain package. However, the main offenders seem to be larger packages like pytorch, numpy, scipy, etc.
If I run the pip install command multiple times in a row, it will fail on a different package each time.
I watch the network traffic in nload/btm/task manager. Every time it does the same thing: traffic stays very strong for several packages, then on a random package, it drops to zero about halfway to 2/3's of the way through the download, then fails with:
14.31 Collecting scipy (from spacenet_processing==0.0.1)
14.35   Downloading https://artifactory.myURL.com/artifactory/api/pypi/primary-pypi/path/to/scipy-1.14.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (41.2 MB)
31.62      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╸          31.7/41.2 MB 14.1 MB/s eta 0:00:01

31.81 TimeoutError: The read operation timed out
###### Long portion of stack trace removed but it's the standard stack trace from a timeout on pip #####
31.81 pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='artifactory.myURL.com', port=443): Read timed out.
------

This is not an internet speed issue. I can take the failed download file and curl it with no issues immediately after. Adjusting the timeout does not help either, it just hangs for the amount of time I set the timeout to.
I am trying to trace down what the issue could be in the internally hosted artifactory.

Found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65777342/5763413
In Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections, click on your network connection, click properties (requires admin permission), scroll down to Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6), and uncheck it.
Went from failing on every time I ran pip to zero issues first time.

That disables ipv6 for the whole box. Worth trying the --timeout option to something higher that 15 seconds. Also worth trying to add an IPv4 entry on the /etc/hosts file for that host. That should override the DNS resolution and use the IPv4 address.
