# How do i bypass a ReadTimeoutError when trying to install a package from pip?

Tags: python, pip

I'm new to package downloading.
I googled how to install pip etc.. i have all the necessary requirements (up to date python, pip, wheels and setuptools).
I moved on to running in my cmd the following line:

```
pip install big-O-calculator
```

which is the package i want to download. when I hit enter I receive a ReadTimeoutError.
how do I resolve it?
the error is:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/big-o-calculator/
```

***if someone can try and download this specific package and tell me if the problem is with the package or my computer.
image of the error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZoMc.png)

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace? I'm unable to reproduce your problem

Comment: added the image

Comment: Not an image please, format it into the question

Comment: alright i hope i understood you, updated again

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: nope, at home, on my regular internet. no special firewall or vpn

Comment: Maybe [this could help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63378765/7867968)?

Comment: tried that solution, hasnt helped